# Listing all virtual machine from all your azure subsciptions using CLI

Tags: azure, virtual-machine, azure-cli

If you have multiple subscription in azure and you want to list vm from all azure subscription. Simple linux command to fetch those details.

Note: Please let me know, if this isn't right way to put Q&A-style question, this if first attempt to share things here in QA format.

Answer (score 1):

Simple cli to list all vms in azure subscriptions

Orig.

```sh
for i in `az account list  -o tsv | awk '{print $3}'`; do az account set --subscription $i; az vm list --query [].[name] --output tsv; done
```

Updated after @anlag comments:

```sh
for i in `az account list  -o tsv | awk '{print $3}'`; do az vm list --subscription $i --query [].[name] --output tsv; done
```

Comment: The `az vm` command supports passing the optional `--subscription` (`-s` for short) parameter, so you don't actually need to change your current subscription to get the same results:

```for i in `az account list  -o tsv | awk '{print $3}'`; do az vm list --subscription $i --query [].[name] --output tsv; done```

Comment: It says ```At line:1 char:4
+ for i in `az account list  -o tsv | awk '{print $3}'`; do az account  ...
+    ~
Missing opening '(' after keyword 'for'.
    + CategoryInfo          : ParserError: (:) [], ParentContainsErrorRecordException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : MissingOpenParenthesisAfterKeyword```